# Temporary off-site deployment with TFS Azure?

Tags: azure, deployment, tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I'm working on a website and I deploy using TFS Azure.

The customer wants me to deploy some iterations to a website that shouldn't be visible on the main website, only after he confirms.

Is there a way to publish shelves to a temporary website? Or maybe a similar low-effort alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at Deployment Slots? http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/

You could create a staging slot where you'd publish the changes and once you get approval, you'd swap the production to the staging slot.

Comment: This ^^^^ but just be careful that if you have a service bus running, your staged release may start to process the messages from your production release